# Form Validation using Yup to check whether inputs value is equal or not

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, yup

I need to make a form validation using Yup to check input type `email1`, `email2`, `email3`, `email4` and `email5` in my React App.

The rule of thumb is easy. Check those `emails` is in valid form and cannot have similar `emails` values.

I am super new to Yup. So what I did is:

```
const message = 'Duplicate emails not allowed';
const incorrect = 'Incorrect email format';

const Schema = Yup.object().shape({
  email1: Yup.string()
    .email(incorrect)
    .oneOf([Yup.ref('email2'), null], message)
    .oneOf([Yup.ref('email3'), null], message)
    .oneOf([Yup.ref('email4'), null], message)
    .oneOf([Yup.ref('email5'), null], message),
  email2: Yup.string()
    .email(incorrect)
    .oneOf([Yup.ref('email1'), null], message)
    .oneOf([Yup.ref('email3'), null], message) 
    .oneOf([Yup.ref('email4'), null], message)
    .oneOf([Yup.ref('email5'), null], message),
  email3: Yup.string()
    .email(incorrect)
    .oneOf([Yup.ref('email1'), null], message)
    .oneOf([Yup.ref('email2'), null], message)
    .oneOf([Yup.ref('email4'), null], message)
    .oneOf([Yup.ref('email5'), null], message),
  email4: Yup.string()
    .email(incorrect)
    .oneOf([Yup.ref('email1'), null], message)
    .oneOf([Yup.ref('email2'), null], message)
    .oneOf([Yup.ref('email3'), null], message)
    .oneOf([Yup.ref('email5'), null], message),
  email5: Yup.string()
    .email(incorrect)
    .oneOf([Yup.ref('email1'), null], message)
    .oneOf([Yup.ref('email2'), null], message)
    .oneOf([Yup.ref('email3'), null], message)
    .oneOf([Yup.ref('email4'), null], message)
});
```

The issue with this method is, it will also detect an error of duplicate emails even the input text is empty. How do I fix this? Is there any better way that I could implement?

Thanks

Comment: if this answer was useful for you please accept it

Answer (score 12):

### use notOneOf instead of oneOf

you must use in this structure

---

```
const ValidationSchema=Yup.object().shape({email1: Yup.string().email(this.incorrect)
  .notOneOf(
    [
      Yup.ref('email2'),
      Yup.ref('email3'),
      Yup.ref('email4'),
      Yup.ref('email5')
    ],
    this.message
  ),

email2: Yup.string()
  .email(this.incorrect)
  .notOneOf(
    [
      Yup.ref('email1'),
      Yup.ref('email3'),
      Yup.ref('email4'),
      Yup.ref('email5')
    ],
    this.message
  ),
email3: Yup.string()
  .email(this.incorrect)
  .notOneOf(
    [
      Yup.ref('email1'),
      Yup.ref('email2'),
      Yup.ref('email4'),
      Yup.ref('email5')
    ],
    this.message
  ),

email4: Yup.string()
  .email(this.incorrect)
  .notOneOf(
    [
      Yup.ref('email1'),
      Yup.ref('email2'),
      Yup.ref('email3'),
      Yup.ref('email5')
    ],
    this.message
  ),
email5: Yup.string()
  .email(this.incorrect)
  .notOneOf(
    [
      Yup.ref('email1'),
      Yup.ref('email2'),
      Yup.ref('email3'),
      Yup.ref('email4')
    ],
    this.message
  )});
```

Comment: Hi @alexfrostwolf. Thanks for suggestions. By using your solutions, I still got the error of duplicate emails even the input text is empty. Others work well. Is there any other way to not detect error on empty fields. Helps are really appreaciated.

Comment: you can use when @ArifMustaffa